# how to run mrjob with hdfs on ubuntu?

Tags: python, java, hadoop, hdfs, mrjob

i am setting hadoop 3.3.1 on ubuntu. I can run jar file with hfds normaly  ( use eclipse, add addition jar lib of hadoop then export). run mrjob local normaly but while i running mrjob with hdfs the errors had come.

```
> python mrjob1.py -r hadoop hdfs:///user/duong/in_mrjob/test.csv
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for hadoop runner
Looking for hadoop binary in /home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/bin...
Found hadoop binary: /home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/bin/hadoop
Using Hadoop version 3.3.1
Looking for Hadoop streaming jar in /home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1...
Found Hadoop streaming jar: /home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.1.jar
Creating temp directory /tmp/mrjob1.duong.20220419.040838.619593
uploading working dir files to hdfs:///user/duong/tmp/mrjob/mrjob1.duong.20220419.040838.619593/files/wd...
Copying other local files to hdfs:///user/duong/tmp/mrjob/mrjob1.duong.20220419.040838.619593/files/
Running step 1 of 2...
  packageJobJar: [/tmp/hadoop-unjar4738492666293922225/] [] /tmp/streamjob6472148930822557702.jar tmpDir=null
  Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
  Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
  Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/duong/.staging/job_1650332864138_0006
  Total input files to process : 1
  number of splits:2
  Submitting tokens for job: job_1650332864138_0006
  Executing with tokens: []
  resource-types.xml not found
  Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
  Submitted application application_1650332864138_0006
  The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1650332864138_0006/
  Running job: job_1650332864138_0006
  Job job_1650332864138_0006 running in uber mode : false
   map 0% reduce 0%
  Task Id : attempt_1650332864138_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

  Task Id : attempt_1650332864138_0006_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

  Task Id : attempt_1650332864138_0006_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

  Task Id : attempt_1650332864138_0006_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

  Task Id : attempt_1650332864138_0006_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

  Task Id : attempt_1650332864138_0006_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

   map 100% reduce 100%
  Job job_1650332864138_0006 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1650332864138_0006_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

  Job not successful!
  Streaming Command Failed!
Counters: 14
    Job Counters 
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Failed map tasks=7
        Killed map tasks=1
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=8
        Other local map tasks=6
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=16209920
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=15830
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=15830
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=15830
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
Scanning logs for probable cause of failure...
Looking for history log in hdfs:///tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging...
Looking for history log in /home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/logs...
Looking for task syslogs in /home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/logs/userlogs/application_1650332864138_0006...

Probable cause of failure:

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)


Step 1 of 2 failed: Command '['/home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.1.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/duong/tmp/mrjob/mrjob1.duong.20220419.040838.619593/files/wd/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip,hdfs:///user/duong/tmp/mrjob/mrjob1.duong.20220419.040838.619593/files/wd/mrjob1.py#mrjob1.py,hdfs:///user/duong/tmp/mrjob/mrjob1.duong.20220419.040838.619593/files/wd/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/duong/in_mrjob/test.csv', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/duong/tmp/mrjob/mrjob1.duong.20220419.040838.619593/step-output/0000', '-mapper', '/bin/sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 mrjob1.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-reducer', '/bin/sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 mrjob1.py --step-num=0 --reducer']' returned non-zero exit status 256.
```

i tried to add jar file which i added when export jar from eclipse
[image]
to Hadoop Classpath:

```
> echo $CLASSPATH
:/home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/lib/*:/home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/apache/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/*
```

here, i copy these file to `/home/duong/hadoop-3.3.1/lib/*` but it still error. How can i fixed it? Thanks

Comment: Unless you have a specific need for mrjob, pyspark might run better. In any case, you need to get the real error from the YARN container logs

Comment: yeah, i run it's for my homeword. I solved the problem, although i use conda env but when use first command, it's use my default python env, so i have to add python-bin to command to choose what env of python i want to use.

Comment: You can use tools like pyenv to fix this